# Java How to use an object in a different Class?

Tags: java, oop, servlets

I have a people class. It has people job inside the class.

And I have filter class. In this class , I create an object. `People people = new People();`

And set their job , `people.setjob="doctor";`

Now, how can I use this object in another class? For example, in checkjob class I write `people.getJob` and nothing happens.

I draw my question for you to understand easily.
[image]

By the way, I'm doing this to get user role. I minimalized the question.

Here is the code:

Login.Java

```
if(dao.check(uname, pass)) {
        UserAccount user = new UserAccount();
        user.setUsername(uname);
        Filter2 loginbean = new Filter2();

        String userValidate = loginbean.authenticateUser(user);

        if(userValidate.equals("Admin_Role")) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("username", uname);
        user.setRole("Admin");
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
    }
        else if (userValidate.equals("Editor_Role")) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("username", uname);
            user.setRole("Editör");
            response.sendRedirect("gorevler.jsp");
        }
```

UserAccount.Java

```
public class UserAccount {
private String username;
private String role;
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getRole() {
    return role;
}
public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
```

Filter2.Java

```
public  String authenticateUser(UserAccount loginBean)
{
    String userName = loginBean.getUsername();

    Connection con = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    String userNameDB = "";
    String passwordDB = "";
    String roleDB = "";

    try
    {
        con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/covid","root","fbfbfb333*");

        statement = con.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select username,role from users");

        while(resultSet.next())
        {
            userNameDB = resultSet.getString("username");

            roleDB = resultSet.getString("role");

            if(userName.equals("emre")  && roleDB.equals("admin")) {
            return "Admin_Role";}
            else if(userName.equals(userNameDB)  && roleDB.equals("editor"))
            return "Editor_Role";
            else if(userName.equals(userNameDB)  && roleDB.equals("user"))
            return "User_Role";
        }
    }
```

Welcome.Java

```
    <body>
<jsp:include page="menu.jsp"></jsp:include>  
<%
if(session.getAttribute("username")==null){
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
UserAccount user = new UserAccount();
String rol = user.getRole();
pageContext.setAttribute("rol", rol);
%>

WELCOME ${username}
${rol }
```

Comment: Instead of describing your code and drawing (??) it, can you please just [edit] your question and show your code as text?

Comment: Okey , i did it.

Comment: @onur It appears as if you create a `UserAccount` object and set some properties, but you are not doing anything with it. You will need to store that object somewhere (in a session for instance) in order to be able to access it at a later point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinitialize it in the other class.  And give it the same properties.